# Replace elements on XContainer including root element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Given an XContainer I would like to completely wrap it's contents (including the root element). The XContainer contains some XML. I am attempting to create an XHTML document by wrapping the XContainer contents in parent elements.

```
 XElement headElement = new XElement("head");
 XElement bodyElement = new XElement("body", container);
 container.ReplaceWith(new XElement("html", headElement, bodyElement));
```

The above does not work. Is this possible? Or do I need to create another XContainer and build it with the contents of the orginal XContainer?

**Update**

Apologies for vague question. Let me add some context. I have a method which takes an XContainer as an argument. I would like to modify this XContainer instance. The desired end result would be the original XContainer contents being "wrapped" in a body element. In the example below the XContainer seems to be unchanged after the call to ReplaceWith(). Meaning the container does not include elemenets, "html, head, or body". Hope this is more clear.

```
  protected void BuildXhtmlDocument(XContainer container)
    {
        XElement headElement = new XElement("head");
        XElement bodyElement = new XElement("body", container);
        container.ReplaceWith(new XElement("html", headElement, bodyElement));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(new XElement("foo", new XElement("bar")));
        Console.WriteLine("Before:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
        Console.WriteLine();

        XContainer container = doc.Root;
        XElement headElement = new XElement("head");
        XElement bodyElement = new XElement("body", container);
        container.ReplaceWith(new XElement("html", headElement, bodyElement));
        Console.WriteLine("After:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
<foo>
  <bar />
</foo>

After:
<html>
  <head />
  <body>
    <foo>
      <bar />
    </foo>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looks like it's behaving perfectly. (This *happens* to be the root element of the document, but it wouldn't have to be.)

Now, to actually be able to help you, we'll need to know what's different about what you're trying to do from the above - or if that *is* what you're trying to do, we'll have to see the difference between my code and yours...

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope that it is more apparent what it is I'm attempting. Thanks for the response.